# best blender render

Tags: render, renderer, blender-2.61

I need to know, what renderer has been used in the [Sintel](http://www.sintel.org/) project. I think it wasn't default Blender Render because default Blender Render renders in horrible quality (If it isn't correct please correct me) . And I need to run it on 64-bit operating system (W7 HP) in blender 2.60. What I was searching, the best was [Sunflow](http://sunflow.sourceforge.net/index.php) yet. What you think about / do you have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they did use the blender internal renderer. Using proper lighting and materials you can get an excellent quality out of the blender renderer. If you are using one of the most recent blender versions you also might want to try the cycles renderer. It ships with blender but is still in beta. But without decent materials and lighting, no renderer will give you satisfying results.

Comment: Also, it's hard doing something wrong using a ray tracer in terms of quality: Good raytracer are just faster.

Answer (score 1):

Sintel used blender internal renderer. A branch was made which had some specific features used in sintel, now most of these features are merged into trunk *(as of 2.64).

Blender now comes with cycles rendering engine if you are after a raytracer which is reasonably competitive with other modern raytracers, though less mature of course.

The last commit to Sunflow was in 2008, seems its no longer in development.

---

Update: as of Blender 2.70 Cycles is almost feature complete, compared to Blender Internal renderer.